# How to use Global python environment instead of virtual on Azure App Service

Tags: python, django, bash, azure

I have a Django web app deployed on Azure App Service. I have integrated a bash script in it which is required for running some python notebooks for DataBricks.
Problem is that when bash script is installing python packages in the virtual environment as expected but DataBricks notebook which it is calling is finding those packages in the global environment.
I have tried deactivating the virtual inside bash script but that doesn't work.
Is there any way to instruct azure app service to use global python environment instead of creating a virtual environment.
Thanks

Comment: What kind of Azure App Service you used? On Linux or Windows?

Comment: I am using Linux.

Comment: Azure App Service on Linux, which be based on Docker. Right?

Comment: No, actually it is integrated with a GitHub repository.

Comment: So the words `I am using LInux` means you used Linux on local, and actually you used App Service on Windows now.

Comment: I have used Linux for both local development as well as on azure app service. Things are working fine on local setup but on azure app service my databricks notebook which are getting called from a bash script is using global environment instead of virtual one.